# transparent object is invisible behind other invisible object

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

I have a model with a transparent part:
[image]

When its in front of an other transparent object (the trouser in this case) the trouser is invisible.

[image]

So what's going wrong?

Here is my Blender file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10bvaUBwSa48Ei6XiOesCCupR6p8CtqT9?usp=sharing

I use eevee and the MMD add-on.

Comment: Hello I can't see the character in the shared file, could you please share the character only?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, even if I don't understand how it works.
I changed the trouser Material>Settings>Blend Mode to Alpha Blend
and for the transparent part Material>Settings>Blend Mode to Alpha Clip